# Configuration file in Windows 8.1

Tags: .net, winforms, app-config, windows-8.1

I am trying to execute following code in form load event of Winforms

```
MessageBox.Show(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1").ToString());
```

Its working and popping 127.0.0.1 in all OS except Windows 8.1 and Windows Server 2012.

On Windows 8.1 its giving me following error

```
        Error - The configuration section cannot contain a CDATA or text element. (C:\Program Files\eRS\Test.exe.Config line 3). Trace -    at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.EvaluateOne(String[] keys, SectionInput input, Boolean isTrusted, FactoryRecord factoryRecord, SectionRecord sectionRecord, Object parentResult)
    at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.Evaluate(FactoryRecord factoryRecord, SectionRecord sectionRecord, Object parentResult, Boolean getLkg, Boolean getRuntimeObject, Object& result, Object& resultRuntimeObject)
    at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSectionRecursive(String configKey, Boolean getLkg, Boolean checkPermission, Boolean getRuntimeObject, Boolean requestIsHere, Object& result, Object& resultRuntimeObject)
    at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSectionRecursive(String configKey, Boolean getLkg, Boolean checkPermission, Boolean getRuntimeObject, Boolean requestIsHere, Object& result, Object& resultRuntimeObject)
    at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSectionRecursive(String configKey, Boolean getLkg, Boolean checkPermission, Boolean getRuntimeObject, Boolean requestIsHere, Object& result, Object& resultRuntimeObject)
    at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSection(String configKey, Boolean getLkg, Boolean checkPermission)
    at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSection(String configKey)
    at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.System.Configuration.Internal.IInternalConfigSystem.GetSection(String sectionName)
    at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection(String sectionName)
    at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.get_AppSettings()
    at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterLib.GetLocalizedPerfCounterMode()
    at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterLib.IsLocalizedMode()
    at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterLib.IsCustomCategory(String machine, String category)
    at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter.Initialize()
    at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter.set_RawValue(Int64 value)
    at System.Net.NetworkingPerfCounters.Initialize()
    at System.Net.Configuration.SettingsSectionInternal..ctor(SettingsSection section)
    at System.Net.Configuration.SettingsSectionInternal.get_Section()
    at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.InitializeSockets()
    at System.Net.IPAddress.InternalParse(String ipString, Boolean tryParse)
    at System.Net.IPAddress.Parse(String ipString)
    at Test.Form1.Form1_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Following is my app.config file contents

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>    <configuration>appSettings>wwgp89LZ6RQNuYqA4QW49%2b54BdPvtS7WTpSIbQD39tBU8g6XgzuTvCbTL%2feaONiaI6S9c0rNsbbJRqjiW4pfjcndQF8Ol%2fxBWbT1ae0HhxAfoq1ZeF9FTq9KD%2bu1fi1QgFqPhbnM3VJMBGMx4QIBRTHQcQpcEsi9xjkSQ1AT4dt5qWAbfonvvHc1HqCtkoAyB8I9PG7HK6l844sCWVqRrUh8%2biICB0K2i1lJkwmlwhPoEqvW%2bHaXuSit1rCYasIn%2balIQ8wVyW8H5y8aNNzWWfEsYJSID%2bI2b379DiyENBLnacTAQ%3d%3d</appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see you pasted your app.config file isn't setup correctly.

You need to open your `appSettings` section properly with `<appSettings>` instead of `appSettings>`

Then you need to put

```
wwgp89LZ6RQNuYqA4QW49%2b54BdPvtS7WTpSIbQD39tBU8g6XgzuTvCbTL%2feaONiaI6S9c0rNsbbJRqjiW4pfjcndQF8Ol%2fxBWbT1ae0HhxAfoq1ZeF9FTq9KD%2bu1fi1QgFqPhbnM3VJMBGMx4QIBRTHQcQpcEsi9xjkSQ1AT4dt5qWAbfonvvHc1HqCtkoAyB8I9PG7HK6l844sCWVqRrUh8%2biICB0K2i1lJkwmlwhPoEqvW%2bHaXuSit1rCYasIn%2balIQ8wVyW8H5y8aNNzWWfEsYJSID%2bI2b379DiyENBLnacTAQ%3d%3d
```

inside of a key/value pair like so:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="keynamehere" value="wwgp89LZ6RQNuYqA4QW49%2b54BdPvtS7WTpSIbQD39tBU8g6XgzuTvCbTL%2feaONiaI6S9c0rNsbbJRqjiW4pfjcndQF8Ol%2fxBWbT1ae0HhxAfoq1ZeF9FTq9KD%2bu1fi1QgFqPhbnM3VJMBGMx4QIBRTHQcQpcEsi9xjkSQ1AT4dt5qWAbfonvvHc1HqCtkoAyB8I9PG7HK6l844sCWVqRrUh8%2biICB0K2i1lJkwmlwhPoEqvW%2bHaXuSit1rCYasIn%2balIQ8wVyW8H5y8aNNzWWfEsYJSID%2bI2b379DiyENBLnacTAQ%3d%3d" />
</appSettings>
```

Try that and see what you get

Comment: Its already <appSettings>. Its working fine on other operating systems. appSettings is actually encrypted and when I decrypt it programmatically , I get a set of key value pair.

Comment: What's on line 3 of your config file? I'm guessing it's that long string. That error you're getting means that app.config file isn't formatted properly. If you don't format it properly then it won't work.

Comment: Then how it is working on other Windows OS? This is not working only with Windows 8.1.

Comment: I can't tell you why it might be doing that. I can, however, tell you what the meaning of the error you're receiving; it means something on line 3 of your config file isn't formatted properly. My one guess to what may be causing it to only happen on Windows 8.1 is that something changed in the config file on the machine you're running it on and it's not the same as the others.

Comment: No.. I am copying a same folder with EXE and config file alone to reproduce it on Windows 8.1. I understand it might be a problem with config file but the only concern is its working with Windows 7. [Sample Project](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/87729348/Test.rar)

Answer (score 0):

I contacted MS. They provided me a HOTFIX which works.

http://hotfixv4.microsoft.com/.NET%20Framework%203.5,%20Windows%208.1%20RTM,%20Windows%20Server%202012%20R2%20RTM/sp2/DevDiv1030738/50727.8605/free/473010_intl_x64_zip.exe

http://hotfixv4.microsoft.com/.NET%20Framework%203.5,%20Windows%208.1%20RTM,%20Windows%20Server%202012%20R2%20RTM/sp2/DevDiv1030738/50727.8605/free/473009_intl_i386_zip.exe )